# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

Here is my Python code:

```py
x,y,z= input("Enter a Three value: ").split() 
comp=input("Company's Name: ")

tkt = intkt

import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("PAY", "PAY", "192.200.168.15/XE")
cursor = connection.cursor()

query="select TICKETNO,PERIOD,PARAMETERVALUE from transaction where PARAMETERCODE = '01' and COMPANYCODE = :comp AND ticketno in {:x, :y, :z}"

cursor.execute( query, (comp,x,y,z))
 
for ticketno,period, PARAMETERVALUE in cursor:
  print(ticketno,period, PARAMETERVALUE)
```

Here is the error when this file is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python-programs\NoOfDaysquery1.py", line 29, in <module>
    cursor.execute( query, (comp,x,y,z))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I'm unable to figure out what the error message is all about and how can I resolve it.

Comment: What did you input for `comp`, `x`, `y`, `z`?

Comment: It would be easy for us to understand if you could elaborate more about what exactly are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just want to run SQL query with empid in(123, 321,432,234) like this .

Answer (score 0):

Try using '(' instead of '{':

```
query="select TICKETNO,PERIOD,PARAMETERVALUE from transaction where PARAMETERCODE = '01' and COMPANYCODE = :comp AND ticketno in (:x, :y, :z)"
```